# Excel: check time difference depending on cell values

Tags: excel, vba

I have two columns in an excel like:

```
BoxA1000 | 7/4/2013 15:00:43 - User
BoxA1001 | 7/4/2013 15:01:43 - User
BoxA1002 | 7/4/2013 15:02:43 - User
BoxA1003 | 7/4/2013 15:03:43 - User
BoxA1000 | 7/4/2013 15:04:43 - User
```

and for every row I want to find if there is a previous row where it's first column's cell contains the same value (BoxA1000) and then to see what is the time difference of the second column's cell and put it at a new cell at the third row.

For the example above I want the result to be

```
BoxA1000 | 7/4/2013 15:00:43 - User | NO previous entry
BoxA1001 | 7/4/2013 15:01:43 - User | NO previous entry
BoxA1002 | 7/4/2013 15:02:43 - User | NO previous entry
BoxA1003 | 7/4/2013 15:03:43 - User | NO previous entry
BoxA1000 | 7/4/2013 15:04:43 - User | 00:04:00 (or) 4 minites (or) something like that
```

How can I do that with macros?

Answer (score 0):

Additional assumptions: no column titles, data range continuous and start in `Range("A1")`, there is only one possible repeat of any A column entry.

```
Sub test_Solution()

Dim arrBox As Variant
    arrBox = Range(Range("A1"), Range("B1").End(xlDown))
Dim boFound As Boolean

Dim i As Long, j As Long
For i = 1 To UBound(arrBox, 1)
    For j = 1 To i
        If arrBox(i, 1) = arrBox(j, 1) And i <> j Then
            'here we found
            Cells(i, 3) = Format(arrBox(j, 2) - arrBox(i, 2), "h:m:s")
            boFound = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j
    If Not boFound Then Cells(i, 3) = "No previous entry"
    boFound = False
Next i
End Sub
```